# WGL: possible to find offscreen context and render to window?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, webgl, chromium

There is an interesting browser framework called [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), which is basically a wrapper around the Chromium browser engine.

I'm interested in using it to redistribute WebGL-based games for the desktop.  However Awesomium only supports rendering using a pixel buffer sent to the CPU, even though the WebGL context itself is based on a real hardware-accelerated OpenGL context.  This is inefficient for real-time high-performance games and can kill the framerate on low-end machines.

Awesomium may eventually fix this, but it got me thinking: is it possible to search a process for an offscreen OpenGL context and render it directly to a window?  This would avoid the inefficient rendering method, keeping rendering entirely on the GPU.  I'm using a native C++ app on Windows, so presumably this will involve WGL specifics.  Also since Chromium is a multithreaded browser engine it may involve finding an OpenGL context on a different thread or event a different process.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to search a process for an offscreen OpenGL context and render it directly to a window?

No, it it not possible. If the opengl context is created for the OS buffer, then it is not possible to redirect it to other buffer and other opengl context.

Maybe you can use shared opengl resources (if both opengl contexts are created using such option).